# How to calculate Coordinates of the point in given rectangular map based on distance to 4 vertices

Tags: c#, algorithm

with an available map, is there any algorithm find way to calculate coordinates of the point in given rectangular map based on distance to 4 vertices.

Example:
Map height = 330, Map width = 400, actual distance from point to 4 vertices of rectangular are 291, 258, 419, 396 respectively

Now, I want to find coordinates of this point to aligned perpendicular to the edges.
I already have a way to calculate the altitude and then deduce the sides of the right triangle, but it quite a lot of dependent conditions.

Thank everyone!

Try: the altitude and then deduce the sides of the right triangles.

Expecting: a more concise way

Comment: Hi, you should check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Question related to geometry should be as visual as possible, also you mentioned trying an approach, can you also put the same code from your approach in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the formula to calculate the height of a triangle based on the length of its three sides (which you know).
[image]

https://owlcalculator.com/geometry/triangle-height-calculator

Answer (score 1):

Having width `w` and height `h`, we can write three equations for squared distances

```
d1^2 = x^2 + y^2 + a^2
d2^2 = (w-x)^2 + y^2 + a^2
d4^2 = x^2 + (h-y)^2 + a^2
```

If we subtract second one from the first one, we'll get

```
d1^2-d2^2 = 2*w*x - w^2
x = (d1^2-d2^2+ w^2) / (2*w)
```

Similar for difference of the first and last equation to get `y`

Comment: @quangtuvn Is my answer unclear?